# Java: "Couldn't find the target main class to run after checking the Java version" when running a popular .jar file to clean Git repository (BFG)

Tags: java, git, maven, github, mainclass

### BFG REPO CLEANER

I am attempting to clean up a Git repository (remove passwords) using BFG repo cleaner:

- https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/tree/master
- https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

This is a popular project recommended even officially by GitHub as per:

- https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository
- https://medium.com/@vs28031996/remove-git-history-with-bfg-repo-cleaner-866808826eea
- [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history)

### INTENDED USAGE

The intended operation as I understand it is:

1. Ensure current Java is installed (Java 8)
2. Download current BFG .jar file (all versions [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/madgag/bfg/), now 1.14.0), and put in .git folder for project you want to affect.
3. Create `passwords.txt` file in same directory with each password you want replaced on a different line.
4. Ensure the most current commit has the sensitive data (passwords) removed manually.
5. Run `java -jar bfg.jar --replace-text passwords.txt` and it will clean the older commits.

### ERROR

However, this is returning the following error, both from Administrator cmd and from Ubuntu on Windows:

```
Couldn't find the target main class to run after checking the Java version.

The attribute should be in the Jar manifest and called Main-Class-After-UseNewerJava-Check
```

### MAIN CLASS

The mainClass is defined here it appears in the code, although I don't know Java or how Java projects work (I code C++ and C#):

https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/blob/master/bfg/build.sbt

```
mainClass := Some("use.newer.java.Version8")
packageOptions in (Compile, packageBin) +=
  Package.ManifestAttributes( "Main-Class-After-UseNewerJava-Check" -> "com.madgag.git.bfg.cli.Main" )
```

### JAVA VERSIONS

I uninstalled and reinstalled Java 8 in Windows and get from cmd java -version:

```
java version "1.8.0_401"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_401-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.401-b10, mixed mode)
```

From Ubuntu on Windows I get:

```
openjdk version "11.0.21" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Both of these give the same error, even just from `java -jar bfg.jar` with no other commands.

### COMPUTER SPECIFIC ISSUE

I tested on another Windows system, and this does not provide the same error from `java -jar bfg.jar` (it provides the help information).

So this is clearly a single computer system related issue, although I am not sure what.

**Is there any probably reason one Windows computer would provide the error above and another would run it smoothly?**

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Downloading and running jars directly from maven central loses all meta information about dependencies and you don’t want to do that.

Comment: Thanks Thorbjorn! Okay, so as someone who knows C# and C++ but nothing about Java, how do I correctly download and run the jar file? The main project links the Maven download on the right as "Download 1.14.0" with a big link: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Comment: It appears I was mistaken and https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/madgag/bfg/1.14.0/bfg-1.14.0.jar is a fat jar which works to the help message on my Intel Mac with OpenJDK 18.

Comment: Do you mean if you run `java -jar bfg-1.14.0.jar` from a command line in the folder you download it to, you get something other than my error I posted above? That would be helpful to clarify if so then it is a problem on my end, although I am not sure what. Thanks again.

Comment: I just tested and it does work on another computer system, so the problem is with one computer although I don't know what...

Comment: Try disabling any kind of antivirus and firewall software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to run further than that on my machine (MacBook, OpenJDK 18)

```
ravn@freewifi /tmp % java -version
openjdk version "18.0.2.1" 2022-08-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu18.32+13-CA (build 18.0.2.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu18.32+13-CA (build 18.0.2.1+1, mixed mode, sharing)
ravn@freewifi /tmp % curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/madgag/bfg/1.14.0/bfg-1.14.0.jar
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13.8M  100 13.8M    0     0  8101k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 8100k
ravn@freewifi /tmp % echo muh > pass
ravn@freewifi /tmp % git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/.git/
ravn@freewifi /tmp % java -jar bfg-1.14.0.jar --replace-text pass

Using repo : /private/tmp/.git

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at use.newer.java.Util.invokeMainMethod(Util.java:89)
    at use.newer.java.Util.executeMainProgram(Util.java:28)
    at use.newer.java.Util.checkJavaVersionAndExecuteMainProgram(Util.java:18)
    at use.newer.java.Version8.main(Version8.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find 'HEAD' in /private/tmp - are you sure that exists?
```

Note, the error message you see may have been triggered later than this .  You should be able to replicate this on your system.

Comment: Thanks Thorbjorn. I appreciate your taking the time to test. I ended up testing on another computer where it worked if I saved the jar to a new folder. It turned out to be the folder that I was running it inside in Windows on that one hard drive must have had some bad permissions. But moving that folder to a new location, it now runs fine.

So for anyone else who comes across this - beware of windows folder permissions. Try making a new root folder in your drive and test it in there to see. Thanks again.

Comment: I still suspect your antivirus software

Comment: I only have windows security (built into windows 10/11) on default windows settings. Not sure why moving folders would affect that? It also wouldn't work when I pulled the drive and ran it on another computer by Sata to usb until I moved the folder. Definitely was the folder it seems.

Comment: You may want to open a new question about this on super user. Sounds like a learning experience